# Check anti-virus status in C#

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, antivirus

I need to check a group of servers to see whether the anti virus is up-to-date and running. Tricky thing is that they are spread over Windows 2003 and 2008 servers and I need to be able to check them all.

Is there any way of doing this with C# or VB.NET?

I have briefly looked around using WMI, but it appears on 2008/win7 computers Microsoft has changed what information they give back to you.

In summary, I need the following:

- AV name
- AV version
- AV Up-to-Date
- AV Enabled/Running

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample can be found [here](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/09/14/how-to-check-antivirus-installed-using-c/) using WMI as you mentioned. The poster states this is being done on a Win 7 machine; so the code below should get you started...

```
ConnectionOptions _connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
//Not required while checking it in local machine.
//For remote machines you need to provide the credentials
//options.Username = "";
//options.Password = "";
_connectionOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
_connectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
//Connecting to SecurityCenter2 node for querying security details
ManagementScope _managementScope = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\SecurityCenter2", ipAddress), _connectionOptions);
_managementScope.Connect();
//Querying
ObjectQuery _objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
ManagementObjectSearcher _managementObjectSearcher =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(_managementScope, _objectQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection _managementObjectCollection = _managementObjectSearcher.Get();
if (_managementObjectCollection.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (ManagementObject item in _managementObjectCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item["displayName"]);
        //For Kaspersky AntiVirus, I am getting a null reference here.
        //Console.WriteLine(item["productUptoDate"]);

        //If the value of ProductState is 266240 or 262144, its an updated one.
        Console.WriteLine(item["productState"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was the productState I was originally confused by. This answer led me to: http://www.neophob.com/2010/03/wmi-query-windows-securitycenter2/   which helps with more info about the product state. Also found that securityCenter2 is Vista SP1+ apprently.

Comment: A query ,can we get teh antivirus upto date feature in Windows 7?? @Aaron McIver

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your environment is setup you may need to specify your security and permissions. You should also note that **some antivirus products (like McAfee) do not make data available through WMI**.

You can query the Antivirus information from WMI using this snippet:

```
string computer = Environment.MachineName;  
string wmipath = @"\\" + computer + @"\root\SecurityCenter";  
string query = @"SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct";

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmipath, query);  
ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject result in results)  
{  
    // do something with `result[value]`);
}
```

Comment: I wonder how WHS gets information on the client machine to know whether you have AV installed or not...as McAfee is one of those options; could be vendor specific I gather.

Comment: @Arron I am really fuzzy on how the detection works, but I remember it has to do with the McAfee eOrchestrator crud.

Comment: Thanks for the answer greg. Appears to work on xp/vista (pre-sp1) and nt 2003. Going through more testing now.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add not on Server platforms (2003-2008) as they do not have the namespace to check